# Android Studio Collapsing Toolbar Layout overridden by unknown layout

Tags: android, mobile, layout, toolbar

I am a high school student currently creating my first mobile app in Android Studio. So far, I have created a new scrolling activity to what will be my "Events" page and it works perfectly fine when navigating through my home page to "Events". Attached are screenshots of what the developer's view and when the emulator actually runs. When I open the emulator, it will display the red "Foothillers" but immediately some container seems to override the appbar component. I have made the toolbar_layout and toolbar components transparent to only display the appbar in red. But, I have searched through my code to try and find what is covering and saying "Events".

Below is the developing view and emulator view, along with the events activity code
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho4nC.jpg)

And below (2) is the code to the activity_events and the component tree

[Second Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwUqm.jpg)